# jquery.post() getting and returning php jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am doing next...

*request in php from html (jQuery)*

```
$.post("index.php?res=ok", { username: user, userpass: pass }, function(data) {
    $("#signin_ok").html("You sign in now "+data.name+". Your password is: "+data.pass);
    $("#signin_ok").show()
    .animate({fontSize:"120%"}, 100).css({color:"#32CD32"})
    .animate({fontSize:"100%"}, 100)
    .animate({fontSize:"100%"}, 3000)
    .animate({fontSize:"120%"}, 200, function() {
        $(this).css({display:"none"});
    });
});
```

*return from php in html (jQuery)*

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['res']) && $_REQUEST['res'] == "ok") {
    if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['userpass'])) {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $userpass = $_POST['userpass'];
        echo json_encode(array("name" => $username, "pass" => $userpass));
    }
}
```

but returns "You sign in now **undefined**. Your password is: **undefined**"

What's wrong? How to fix it?

P.S.

When I add "json" like this

```
$.post("index.php?res=ok", { username: user, userpass: pass }, function(data) {
    . . . . . . 
    . . . . . .
}, "json");
```

no reaction

What was going on???

Comment: Have you tried to use fiddler or firebug to see what the server is passing back?

Comment: Do a console.log(data) and see (in Chrome for example) what is the result.
If the result is string, you'll have to eval() it

Comment: Result is `{"name":"sabotagnik","pass":"66666666666666"}` I'll must eval() it in PHP or in JS? If in PHP: `$arr = array("name" => $username, "pass" => $userpass); eval("\$arr = \"$arr\";"); echo json_encode($arr);` and result is `"Array"`

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the JSON headers to the PHP script with

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
// then your code
```

Also, seems your just returning the passed data, why don't you just use user and pass as the data, rather than data.user and data.pass?

Comment: no reaction :(. It is just an example.. that is why I don't use user. I need return data from php only

Answer (score 0):

Does this do the trick?

```
$.post("index.php?res=ok", { username: user, userpass: pass }, function(data) {
    $("#signin_ok").html("You sign in now "+data[0].name+". Your password is: "+data[0].pass);
    $("#signin_ok").show()
    .animate({fontSize:"120%"}, 100).css({color:"#32CD32"})
    .animate({fontSize:"100%"}, 100)
    .animate({fontSize:"100%"}, 3000)
    .animate({fontSize:"120%"}, 200, function() {
        $(this).css({display:"none"});
    });
});
```

Comment: Don't forget to make sure your PHP script sets the JSON headers: header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Content-type: application/json');

Comment: I have tried next... `if(isset($_REQUEST['res']) && $_REQUEST['res'] == "ok") {
    if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['userpass'])) {
        header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
        header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
        header("Content-type: application/json"); 
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $userpass = $_POST['userpass'];
        echo json_encode(array("name" => $username, "pass" => $userpass));
    }
}` but It doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I'll respond with a $.ajax call because that tends to be what I use, since $.post just wraps $.ajax anyways...

```
$.ajax({

     type: "POST",
     url: "index.php?res=ok",
     data: { "username" : user, "userpass": pass },
     success: function(msg) {

          var data = $.parseJSON(msg);
          alert(data.username);
          alert(data.userpass);

     }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem myself, I think so :)

I have created new file (new.php):

```
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['res']) && $_REQUEST['res'] == "ok") {
    if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['userpass'])) {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $userpass = $_POST['userpass'];
        $arr = array("name" => $username, "pass" => $userpass);
        echo json_encode(array("name" => $username, "pass" => $userpass));
    }
}
?>
```

and passed request from HTML to PHP (new.php)

```
. . .
$.post("new.php", { "username": user, "userpass": pass, "res": "ok" }, function(data) {
    $("#signin_ok").html("You sign in now "+data['name']+". Your password is: "+data['pass']);
    console.log(data);
    $("#signin_ok").show()
        .animate({fontSize:"120%"}, 100).css({color:"#32CD32"})
        .animate({fontSize:"100%"}, 100)
        .animate({fontSize:"100%"}, 3000)
        .animate({fontSize:"120%"}, 200, function() {
            $(this).css({display:"none"});
        });
}, "json");
. . .
```

and I got result :)
but it's stupid, why it's doesn't work in index.php???

Comment: Oh my God. It was so easy. I have added `exit;` after `json_encode(..);` and that is all